# embedding existing php recordset within new mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have an existing recordset that retrieves all the information from a table in mysql called $rrows. What I am hoping to do is to use this existing recordset within a new mysql query.

For example I have the following line that retrieves the "product code" from one table:

```
<?php echo $rrows['productcode']; ?>
```

I am trying to then gather the respective images from a new table using this productcode by something similar to:

```
<img src="<?php

mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);
mysql_set_charset('utf8');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM furnimages WHERE productcode='$rrows['productcode']'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '' . $row['photo'] . '';   
}
mysql_close($con);
?>">
```

Can this be done? Originally I was going to LINK tables together to get all the information, but this doesnt work as some of the product codes in the main do not have corresponding data in the 'furnimages' table.....

Thanks in advance!
JD

Comment: `JOIN` the tables as you originally intended. If the `JOIN` does not produce the results you want, it's because you don't have the correct query.

Comment: If the data exists, it should work as written.

Comment: thanks for the comments - the above code spits out a syntax error which is why I put it up here on stackoverflow - didnt mean to offend anyone! Will try and figure it out.

Comment: @JD2011: if you get a syntax error, then say what the error is (cut 'n paste it). It's like going to see a doctor and then not saying a word and wondering why they can't help you, instead of simply saying "hey, my leg's broken"

Comment: thanks Marc- having reviewed everything I don't actually need to incoporate such a field in my sites management system so have stripped it out - appreciate the comment though - still very new to all this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) is your best friend here.

```
$sql = <<<sql
SELECT * FROM furnimages 
WHERE productcode=%d
sql;

$result = mysql_query(sprintf($sql, $rrows['productcode']));
```

So, %d is the placeholder in the string to swap in the second argument in the call to sprintf();

%d denotes an integer placeholder; if $rrows['productcode'] is a string, use %s.

This is better than simply quoting value of the variable as it adds a type constraint which reduces the risk of nasty sql injection.

It also makes it eminently more readable.

Check out the [PHP Data Objects extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), though, because that really is the only way forward for this type of thing.

Comment: worked like a charm - thanks very much!! Looking at the php data objects extension now for more education on the subject.

Comment: *"This is better than simply quoting value of the variable as it adds a type constraint which reduces the risk of nasty sql injection."* Sorry, but I have to disagree with "better". With this approach, to prove that you are safe you have to look at *two* places: the query (where some variables would be sanitized with `%d`) *and* the `sprintf` params (where the rest would be escaped). In my book, that's *worse* than having to look at just `sprintf`. It also leaves you open to maintenance-induced bugs, and it certainly does not reduce the risk (both methods are 100% proof if done correctly).

Comment: _where some variables would be sanitized with %d_  There is only one variable in the query, and if you had more, you'd use more placeholders, not put the variables directly in thw query.  Not quite with you there.